# Unable to Click on Element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am unable to click on the element. I am able to locate it with xpath, the object with statements
"element.getText()"
 returns correct values
"element.isDisplayed()"
 returns true 
but when i say "element.click()" throws an exception
"Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"
The above exception is thrown in selenium 2.34 and higher versions.

When I use older selenium version say "2.25" it doesn't throw an exception but the click has no effect.
I am using FF browser on Win7 machine.Below is the HTML

```
<div class="dojoxGrid-row dojoxGrid-row-over row-read" style="">
 <table class="dojoxGrid-row-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="dojoxGrid-cell " style="width:36px;" idx="0" tabindex="-1">
    <td class="dojoxGrid-cell gridColFrom " style="width:150px;" idx="1" tabindex="-1">
    <td class="dojoxGrid-cell gridColType " style="width:16px;" idx="2" tabindex="-1"/>
    <td class="dojoxGrid-cell gridColAttach " style="width:16px;" idx="3" tabindex="-1"/>
    <td class="dojoxGrid-cell gridColSub dojoxGrid-cell-over" style="width:400px;" idx="4"       tabindex="-1">
      <span style="white-space: nowrap;" title="(No subject)">(No subject)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="dojoxGrid-cell " style="width:72px;" idx="5" tabindex="-1">Tue May 13</td>
    <td class="dojoxGrid-cell gridColHov " style="width:16px;" idx="6" tabindex="-1">
    <td class="dojoxGrid-cell gridColFlag " style="width:16px;" idx="7" tabindex="-1">
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Post element's html contents please

Comment: How are you testing the element's visibility before clicking it?

Comment: element.isDisplayed() returns true.

Comment: What do you get with `element.isEnabled()`?

Comment: element.isEnabled() returns true

Comment: what exactly are you trying to click?

Comment: I am trying to click the span element.

Comment: What object locator are you using? Try by using xpath starting from the div element.

Comment: Yes I do use Xpath from the div element. For confirmation the getText() gives the value of the spam element correctly. I can perform actions like mouseover. Click is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with**

What you're seeing is commonly caused by multiple elements on the screen matching the search criteria. WebElement.findElement returns the first match, which may not actually be visible. You can check by calling "isDisplayed" on it.

Try to locate that element using same xpath in firebug and check whether it is showing element which is visible on screen.

Comment: I use firebug and the XPATH correctly points to the element of interest. I cofirm this reading the text of the element also. As mentioned above I do check the value "isDisplayed" which is true.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click element using jsExecuter:

```
JavascriptExecutor myJSExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)myDriver;
myJSExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", myElement);

//where myDriver and myElement are already defined WebDriver and WebElement
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your application uses [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) for UI. I faced same problem while clicking on an element which has dojo property and I solved it using `JavaScriptExecutor` in similar way as you mentioned above. The other solution to this problem is use `.sendKeys(Keys.Enter)`.